# Redux Saga - React Native - Proper setup? Actions issue?

Tags: react-native, redux-saga

I'm working with redux-saga for the first time and I'm not having luck with it at the moment.  I'm thinking my actions aren't being passed into my saga, but I'm not sure??  Below I've provided a sample of the code.  I'm currently not passing in any API calls, just some functions to get this going.

App.js File:

```
import React from "react";
import Setup from "./src/boot/setup";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './src/store';

export default class App extends React.Component {

render() {

  return (
  <Provider store={store}>
  <Setup/>
  </Provider>
 );
 }
}
```

store.js

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import AllReducers from '../src/reducers';
import rootSaga from '../src/saga'; 


const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()

const store = createStore(
  AllReducers,
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
);

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export default store;
```

saga.js

```
import { call, put, takeEvery, takeLatest } from "redux-
saga/effects";
**import {receiveHelloWorld } from "./actions";
import { REQUEST_HELLO_WORLD } from "./actions/types";**

function* helloWorld(action) {
try {

   yield put(receiveHelloWorld("Hello world from redux saga!"));
 } catch (e) {
  yield put(receiveHelloWorld("Hello world from redux saga!"));
 }
}


export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(REQUEST_HELLO_WORLD, helloWorld);
}
```

reducer.js

```
import { RECEIVE_HELLO_WORLD } from "../actions";

export default (state = "", { type, text = "" }) => {
  switch (type) {
   case RECEIVE_HELLO_WORLD:
   return text;
default:
  return state;
 } 
};
```

actionCreator.js (this is importing into the actions index.js file)

```
import { REQUEST_HELLO_WORLD, RECEIVE_HELLO_WORLD } from './types';

 export const requestHelloWorld = () => ({ 
  type: REQUEST_HELLO_WORLD 
 });
  export const receiveHelloWorld = text => ({ 
  type: RECEIVE_HELLO_WORLD, text 
});
```

sagaScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Text,  Button } from "native-base";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import styles from "../styles/styles";

import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { requestHelloWorld } from "../actions";

class SagaScreen extends React.Component {

componentDidMount() {
 this.props.requestHelloWorld();
}

render() {
  return (
    <Container style={styles.container}>        
      <Text style={{marginTop: 50 }}> {this.props.helloWorld} </Text>
    </Container>

   );
 }
}

 const mapStateToProps = state => ({ helloWorld: state.helloWorld });

  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators({ requestHelloWorld }, dispatch);

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
(SagaScreen);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update Your saga:
saga.js

```
import { REQUEST_HELLO_WORLD, RECEIVE_HELLO_WORLD } from "./actions/types";
function* helloWorld(action) { 
   try {
      yield put({type: RECEIVE_HELLO_WORLD, text: "Hello world from redux saga!"});
   } catch (e) {
      //Handling for error
   }
}
export default function* watchStartSaga () {
  yield takeLatest(REQUEST_HELLO_WORLD, helloWorld);
}
```

//Updated Answer
Create new file. **index.js** in directory src/saga.

index.js

```
import { fork } from "redux-saga/effects";
import watchStartSaga from "./saga";

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield fork(watchStartSaga);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. No luck on that one though.

Comment: OK. I miss one thing for rootSaga in store. You need one place to start saga. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm having to restructure everything at this point.  Need to regroup.  Thank you for reaching out though.  It's greatly appreciated HSU!

Comment: You're Welcome, Adam.